# Make a pdf file with QTextEdit and QGraphicsview

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to print an image from QGraphicsView and Qtextedit into same pdf file, how can I achieve that? I tried some ways, but always seemed to fail.

**EDIT**
I can do both separately using the following code. I tried to make them to work together
 but can't. A naive workaround would be cloning the qtextedit and then creating
 the image then embedding the image in qtextedit as HTML, then printing and deleting the image.
I'd prefer to use only PyQt without any external dependencies!
thank you!

> def savePDF(self):
>
> > ```
> >   filename = self.saveDialog()<br>
> >   if filename.isEmpty():
> >       return
> >   printer = QPrinter()
> >   printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.Letter)
> >   printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
> >   printer.setOutputFileName(filename)
> >   paint = QPainter(printer)
> >   self.qtexteditz.print_(printer)
> > ```

```
def savePNG(self):
    out = QPixmap(2000,2000)
    self.tmp.append(out)
    paint = QPainter(out)
    self.tmp.append(paint)

    targ = QRectF(0,0,2000,2000)
    src = QRect(0,0,2000,2000)
    paint.fillRect(targ, Qt.white)
    self.graphicsviewz.render(paint,targ,src)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using reportlab, [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reportlab/2.7][1]

Comment: Thanks for your response =). I'd prefer not to use other dependencies. Also, I updated my question!